# ansible raw multiple commands

Tags: ssh, ansible

I have a group of LANCOM WiFi APs.
They support SSH, but they have a custom interface (no python).

When I try running Ansible's `command` `shell` and `script` modules I get a long error. It works with the `raw` module though.

I have a long script that has to be run all in one SSH session. Is there a way for ansible to pipe the .txt file to a group of routers with the raw module in a playbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add "gather_facts: False" between hosts and tasks. (from: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-project/WP4XM_7PUz0)

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the raw module basically just performs a pure ssh call to the target host, passing any arguments on the ssh command line. So there's no way to pipe a text file to the command within ansible. However you could probably do a very similar thing by reading the file into an ansible variable and then passing that to the raw command.  Something along these lines:

```
- hosts: waps
  vars:
      command_string: "{{ lookup('file', '/path/to/commands.txt') }}"
  tasks:
      raw: "{{ command_string }}"
```

It might take a bit of effort to get the text file formatting correct, but I see no reason why this wouldn't work.

Edit: Here is a test i just successfully ran.  First, I created a commands.txt file with the following contents:

```
rm -f /tmp/foo.txt
echo one >> /tmp/foo.txt
echo two >> /tmp/foo.txt
if [ -f /tmp/foo.txt ] ; then
  echo three >> /tmp/foo.txt
fi
```

My playbook was pretty much exactly as shown above:

```
- hosts: testhost
  user: test-user
  vars:
    command_string: "{{ lookup('file', '/tmp/commands.txt') }}"

  tasks:
    - debug: var=command_string

    - raw: "{{ command_string }}"
```

When I ran the above, it created the file /tmp/foo.txt on testhost containing the following text:

```
one
two
three
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. It pops out this: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=UY3UML9f

Comment: You probably need to modify the script slightly.  It doesn't really make sense to have commands like "#!/bin/sh" passed on the command line to your target.  See my edits to my answer for a test I just tried that ran successfully.

Comment: This is my file (with new lines):
cd 1
cd 1
ls

Comment: I just tried this on a Linux machine and it worked. Seems like it's the router not having Python installed.

Comment: The [documentation for the raw module](http://docs.ansible.com/raw_module.html) explicitly states "This module does not require python on the remote system" so I'm not sure why you would be getting an error like that unless you're referencing python in your script.

Comment: You might also want to give the [script module](http://docs.ansible.com/script_module.html) a try.  I wasn't familiar with this one and just came across it while looking at the documentation for the raw module.  It states that it also does not require python for it to run.  It will copy your script to the target and then run it locally.

Comment: The thing is I can't copy files. The APs have a system taht only uses SSH to connect to them. Then they have a folder-like navigation with only a few commands to set values.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly because ansible requires python-simplejson to be available for executing all its modules except for `raw` and `script`. All the others require a python installation along with python-simplejson

Comment: I think it is because for some reason even though I use the raw module it still wants python on the client machine. I cant install it since it has a custom OS made for routers.